# gdb+osx: redirecting stdout may cause printf to have a 2**14 bytes buffer?

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb

I attached to a program with gdb in OSX and I want to use `CFShow` in the gdb console etc. However, nothing shows up. `printf` shows nothing as well:

```
(gdb) call (int) printf("Hello\n")
$10 = 6
(gdb) call (int) printf("Hello World!\n")
$11 = 13
```

Apple suggests [the following tip](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn/tn2032.html) for when attaching with gdb, to make the output appear in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) call (void) close(1)
(gdb) call (void) close(2)
(gdb) shell tty
/dev/ttyp1
(gdb) call (int) open("/dev/ttyp1", 2, 0)
$1 = 1
(gdb) call (int) open("/dev/ttyp1", 2, 0)
$2 = 2
```

In xcode's gdb console `tty` gives "`not a tty`", so I tried it in gdb in a terminal. There `tty` does work but after redirecting stdout there's still no output. Also no output if I direct stdout to a file.. :/

Any salvation?

**Update/More-details**:

<strike>On some programs (like TextMate) this method does work. The application I was trying to debug is `/Developer/Applications/Audio/AU\ Lab.app`. For some reason this trick does not work there..</strike>
 Update: seems the real explanation is rather:

If after attaching I redirect stdout before calling `printf` for the first time, it works! If I first `printf` and only then redirect output, output shows up only after doing `printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n")` and then pressing enter (to repeat last command) 327 times.

So I guess redirecting stdout somehow makes libc confused and makes it use a buffer of `2**14` bytes for some reason?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. In the Debugger Console of XCode I have tried it with an Objective-C command line application using the Core Foundation framework; I have also run gdb in a Terminal on the same program. In both cases the `call` s work and return their output to the console. Could you create a new user account and try to give the steps to reproduce the issue from a clean install?

Comment: One more minor comment: According to the documention of `CFType`, the call to `CFShow` should put the output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Of course, `printf` should still work after redirecting `stdout` somewhere else!

Comment: @user847: apparently this method does work for some applications and doesn't work for other(s). see my update. thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with `/Developer/Applications/Audio/AU\ Lab.app` either. In addition, the app is not compiled with debugging symbols enabled (switch `-g` ), so I can access neither the symbols nor the source code itself. If I run gdb on the program, the `call (int) printf(...)` command works fine for me, though. To be specific, the output will appear at the console just as it should.

Comment: @yairchu: Yes, at last I can reproduce the problem by manually redirecting output to a file (it always works on stdout for me, though)! The output is indeed buffered and the buffer is not flushed. If this happened in a regular program, I would use the `call (int) fflush(stdout)` command, but this does not seem to work in gdb - it always crashes.

Comment: There is one thing that I find *extremely* disturbing: Usually, the output is flushed when the file is closed. However, even when manually issuing the close commands (like the Apple page you have linked to suggests) the file where the current output was supposed to go **will not get flushed**! Even when closing the application being debugged and quitting gdb, the output will not appear. The output really is gone! So it seems something is going on that goes beyond buffering output ...

Comment: @user847: weird, over here, the output is flushed when closing the program! (checked with gdb in Terminal and redirecting stdout to the tty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be related to a peculiarity of your setup. Here are a couple of further suggestions you could try to identify the source of the problem:

1. First, check the way the debugger is launched - are you using the command line in the Terminal or is it through some GUI which may submit additional command line arguments beyond your control? (You mentioned XCode, but I don't see why you would debug the program you mentioned through XCode? And actually I am not sure how XCode executes gdb, so please try to stick to the terminal for now!)
2. Do you have an init-file in your home directory (a file called `.gdbinit` or so) that configures gdb with some options you are unaware of? Here is a description of what gdb does on startup: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html#Startup
3. According to the manual page, using the `-n` option on startup will prevent loading any configuration files: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options Does your problem still persist if you use this switch?
4. One particular set of commands regards gdb's logging behavior: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html#Logging-Output Can you execute `show logging` at the console and check what happens to the output?
5. What is the output of `show inferior-tty`? If it is set to `""` then it will be the same as your gdb console (which is fine). Otherwise, program output will go somewhere else, but this cannot explain the issue you had with output disappearing form interactive gdb commands!

Comment: See new update. In short my own problem is solved now, but there's still a weird phenomenon here to be explained. The reason to debug "AU Lab" in xcode is to debug your Audio-Unit plugins which you can run with "AU Lab". Also I tried this on both my Snow-Leopard desktop and my Leopard laptop and both exhibit the same behavior. No `.gdbinit` and `inferior-tty` is `""`. thanks

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification, I had launched the application on the command line through gdb, not the way you have been doing; so that's why I could not reproduce the problem right away.

Comment: even though a mystery remains (as I've updated my question to reflect it), my original problem is solved. so I marked your answer as accepted